# Bash stdout and/or stderr history log

Tags: bash, shell, command-line, logs, command-history

As you probably know, the `bash` shell's `stdin` is logged to `$HISTFILE` (i.e. usually `~/.history`) and can be accessed with the `history` builtin, and so on.

But the `stdout` & `stderr` are not.

How can set up an automated log of the output of shell commands; in the same manner as the input?

Comment: Not completely so. See `echo ls | bash` and then check history.

Comment: See also: typescript